# Render TTF SDL2.0 opengl 3.1

Tags: opengl, fonts, sdl, sdl-2, opengl-3

I'm working with SDL2.0, and using a (semi modern) opengl (3.1). I'm looking to add a text overlay to my application, and to render TTF in the application. How would I go about this using modern OpenGL?

EDIT:
As per the suggestion of genpfault, I've tried using the SDL_TTF library, but All I'm getting is garbage on screen https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqyCT.png
I've attached a gist of my shaders, which are very simple for this program, and also the snipped I'm using to load the text into surface, and to bind it to the texture. I'm not trying to do anything crazy here at all. Is there anything I'm doing wrong you can see? I'm not really too sure how to debug shaders etc.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7284430

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spent too much time with a black screen before I figured out the actually text data was in the alpha channel.

```cpp
GLuint shader_program_text;

void drawText()
{
    //Render the message to an SDL_Surface, as that's what TTF_RenderText_X returns
    text_font = TTF_OpenFont("bpl_binary/waltographUI.ttf", 50);
    SDL_Color color = {255, 0, 0, 0};
    SDL_Surface* sdl_surface = TTF_RenderText_Blended(text_font, "hello world", color);
    GLuint texture_id;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture_id);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, sdl_surface->w, sdl_surface->h, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, sdl_surface->pixels);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    SDL_FreeSurface(sdl_surface);
    TTF_CloseFont(text_font);

    //glDrawPixels(sdl_surface->w, sdl_surface->h, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, sdl_surface->pixels);
    //FILE* file = fopen("output.txt", "w+");

    //for(int h=0; h<sdl_surface->h; h++)
    //{
    //  
    //  for(int w=0; w<sdl_surface->w; w++)
    //  {
    //      unsigned int xxx = ((unsigned int*)sdl_surface->pixels)[h*sdl_surface->w + w];
    //      /*if(xxx != 0)
    //          fprintf(file, "x", xxx);
    //      else
    //          fprintf(file, " ", xxx);*/
    //      fprintf(file, "%08x ", xxx);
    //  }
    //  fprintf(file, "\n");
    //}

    //fclose(file);

    //MULTIPLY WITH ALPHA TO ACTUALLY SEE SOMETHING

    glUseProgram(shader_program_text);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
    //texcoord; position;
    glVertexAttrib2f(1, 0, 1); glVertexAttrib2f(0, -1, -1); //top left
    glVertexAttrib2f(1, 1, 1); glVertexAttrib2f(0, +1, -1); //top right
    glVertexAttrib2f(1, 0, 0); glVertexAttrib2f(0, -1, +1); //bottom left
    glVertexAttrib2f(1, 1, 0); glVertexAttrib2f(0, +1, +1); //bottom right
    glEnd();

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glUseProgram(0);
}
```

Comment: glBegin and glEnd are not allowed int OpenGL 3+

Comment: hmm so i suppose you use only VBOs then?

Comment: VAO + VBO yes: that mean a lot of code to just perform the same that was done with a simple glDrawPixels (create a texture, create a VBO and create shaders) just to copy some pixels to the screen. I am looking for simpler ways, but I haven't found anything until now.

Comment: @AdrianMaire: since we have to use shaders anyway, maybe this would even be a nice use case for a geometry shader? like supplying the font texture and a 1D-1-Byte-Per-Index (=GL_RED8 afaik) texture containing the string to render, and then rendering one quad (=4 vertex triangle strip) defining the text bounding box. or would that introduce too much overhead? planning my own openGL 4.3 GUI system, and I don't want my game being slowed down by the UI :D

Comment: @nonchip: Every char has is own size, position and so on, so to render a full text just from a char grid is not easy. If you are able to create quality text as this it may be good, but personally, I just have rendered the full text on a texture (the first time the text appeared) with a text library (SDL_TTF or equivalent).

Comment: @AdrianMaire ok, I think I'll do it the "dump everything to texture" way and if I really decide to do shader magic, I think I'd go with signed distance fields anyway, because custom shapes FTW :D

Answer (score 1):

Use [the `pixels` member of the `SDL_Surface`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Surface) returned by a `TTF_Render*()` call to populate a texture.

Comment: I guess that's using the SDL_TTF library? Thanks for the response, I've tried it but I'm not having much luck with it.